# Convert ms timestamp to sequential unique 32 bit number?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hash

I have a table where each record has a field for the timestamp (in ms) from when it was created. This gives a unique ID for each record, as well as sequential ordering. Record 12345678 is different from and comes after 12222222.

There are not records every millisecond, or even every second (although the rate could increase).

My problem is I have a client expecting unique 32-bit IDs. These IDs also need to be numeric, unique and sequential. But the above timestamp currently is ~43 bits.

I could hash them down, but then I lose the sequential and numeric properties. I could chop off the first 10-15 bits or the last, but then I might lose the uniqueness. Someone suggested accepting that the first record isn't from before 1 Jan 2010, so take `timestamp - (40 years)`. I don't love it, and there are enough milliseconds in one year to make that not work.

Any good ways of dealing with this?

Comment: (Does the _table_ know that field to be unique?) Keep the time-stamps randomly accessible by index, use a binary search to establish the index of any given time-stamp, and that index as the ID for _the 32-bit client_. (ROWID?)

Comment: @greybeard you lost me. Have an index into the timestamp?

Comment: `Have an index into the timestamp?` Close: use an index (as in ordinal - or [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search#Iterative)) of each time-stamp actually kept - _not_ as in `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tsi ON table.time_stamp`.

Comment: (`Index stored where` - _what_ `Index`?) While the index/ordinal to communicate to _the 32-bit client_ can of course be stored alongside the time-stamp, it does not _need_ to: if the time-stamps are kept such that they can be accessed by ordinal, the ordinal of any time-stamp can be computed (time and again) given the time-stamp value.

Comment: Now I am thoroughly confused. Let's say I currently have 5 records, with timestamps 100, 105, 116, 157, 199 (yes, those are 8-bit, but keeping it simple). What calculation do I do on each record to generate the new UID to send to client? E.g. for record 105, it is UID 22; and when client sends back 22, how do I go from that to record whose timestamp actually is 105?

Comment: (Actually working on another comment now that I found your comment that you do, indeed, use a DB (add that to the question, along with the SQL-standard applicable, if any)) If those are all your timestamps, the IDs would be 1↔100, 2↔105, 3↔116, 4↔157, 5↔199. You go from 105 to 2 by locating 105 in the ordered list of all time-stamps at position 2.

Comment: Non-SQL; actually in AWS Dynamo (choice of the client). Where would I keep that 1 ↔ 100, 2↔200, etc. mapping? Are you saying I need to download and re-index them with every request? That could get difficult to scale if I hit 1,000s or MMs of records?

Comment: (`Non-SQL` why am I not surprised? `AWS Dynamo` will have to do some reading up) `Where would I keep that […] mapping?` with the time-stamps, "obviously". With SQL, I'd use a view to select data, anyway (and procedures to offer data to the server).

Comment: `why am I not surprised?` ha! I actually like NoSQL for a lot of things. I am not the biggest fan of Dynamo, though. Any math that depends on calculating ordinal numbers will not work necessarily either. What do I do when records are deleted?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to be able to handle records even in ms time difference, there is no way to squeeze the timestamp down to 32bit without the risk of collisions. Simply because there might be more than 2^32 records some day.

How I understand your problem, you need to be able to find the records later by the id and you are not able to store the 32bit id in the records.
is this right?

I see the following possibilities:

1. You can ensure that there is no more than one record every 4s than you can simply remove the last 12 bits of your 43bit timestamp.But this will no longer work if your timestamp increases to 44bits
2. if you can modify the timestamp of your records you can take the above approach and if two records are to close together, you can simply modifiy the timestamp of the later one to make the upper 32 bits of the timestamp unique. This will work as long as the average rate of records is less than one records every 4 seconds. [Disadvantage: the timestamps of the records are no longer exactly the creation time but still more or less ok]

Comment: I am willing to accept the risk of 2^32 records in my table. If we have 4.3BN records in my table, that is a good problem to have! I am sure there will rarely be more than a few thousand records in the table. This is a perfect case for a sequence ID that databases generate, but I simply do not have it here.

Comment: I probably should have named this question, "how to have unique sequential record IDs in a table when the DB doesn't generate it for you!"

Comment: If all Records are created by one instance, you could simply use a static counter to generate the IDs (be aware to avoid race-conditions if more than one thread/task call the creation-method).

Comment: Agreed.... and if I had control over the record-creator, I would do some form of ordinal/atomic counter, have a `seq_id` field or similar, with some back-off or race-prevention logic. But I don't. All I have is access to the data generated by it.